# How to extract the type argument from a Java bean property?

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans, type-erasure

I have an arbitrary Java bean like the following:

```
class SomeBean {

    public Map<String, SomeOtherBean> getOtherBeans() { ... }
    public void setOtherBeans(Map<String, SomeOtherBean> otherBeans) { ... }

}
```

and I would like to extract the type `SomeOtherBean` with a generic method. In the presence of Java's type erasure, is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, even with erasure in the game.

The following implementation from Magnolia's `TypeMappingImpl` [1] (dual-licensed *under the GPL and Magnolia Network Agreement*) extracts all type arguments up to the first level from the setter method:

```
private List<Class<?>> inferGenericTypes(Method method) {
    List<Class<?>> inferredTypes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    Type[] parameterTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
    for (Type parameterType : parameterTypes) {
        if (parameterType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) parameterType;
            for (Type t : type.getActualTypeArguments()) {
                if (t instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                    // this the case when parameterized type looks like this: Collection<List<String>>
                    // we care only for raw type List
                    inferredTypes.add((Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) t).getRawType());
                } else if (t instanceof WildcardType) {
                    WildcardType wildcardType = (WildcardType) t;
                    if (wildcardType.getUpperBounds().length > 0) {
                        // upper bounds (? extends Number)
                        inferredTypes.add((Class<?>) wildcardType.getUpperBounds()[0]);
                    } else {
                        // lower bounds (? super Number)
                        inferredTypes.add((Class<?>) wildcardType.getLowerBounds()[0]);
                    }
                } else {
                    inferredTypes.add((Class<?>) t);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return inferredTypes;
}
```

[1]: from the package `info.magnolia.jcr.node2bean.impl`